# Oracle-xe 11g installation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, software-installation, oracle

I tried to install the **oracle-xe 11g rpm** package. I tried to follow the oracle pdf provided by the oracle site. I run:

```
rpm -ivh oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

and I get the following:

```
glibc >= 2.3.4 is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
libaio >= 0.3.104 is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
/bin/sh is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
```

I cannot seem to update or install these. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu `.rpm` files cannot be run or installed.

First you should convert the `.rpm` file to `.deb` which is the installation file type in ubuntu.

```
sudo alien -d [FILE NAME].rpm
```

Then there will be a `.deb` file in the same folder. You need to install it by the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i [FILE NAME].deb
```